# This computer can't verify the identity of the RD Gateway

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, ethernet, windows-server

I am trying to connect to my Windows server using a specific gateway, using the command:

```
mstsc /v:srv-windows /g:192.168.31.254
```

But then i receive the message: "This computer can't verify the identity of the RD Gateway"
Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who is managing the Remote Desktop gateway? You need to add the certificate being provided by the RD gateway to your trusted root authorities and connect via hostname - not IP. But, if the RD gateway is setup properly and you use a hostname instead of an IP address for the gateway, this is a non-issue.

Comment: Im the manager... Do you know where do i go to generate this certificate? Do i need to generate from the remote desktop gateway?

Comment: It is in the properties of the RDG server in the RDG manager console. Look for the SSL certificate settings. You’ll need to either use a trusted certificate from an online cert authority. Or, you’ll need to generate and use a self-signed cert and import it on each client to remove the security warning. There are numerous ways to generate a self-signed cert on Windows. please look it up.

Comment: Thanks. Ill try to generate a certificate to the gateway